# Can't store dates from input value

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp, varchar

```
UPDATE blogs SET start_date = '11/27/2012 00:00',end_date = '11/27/2012 00:00' WHERE id='9'
```

This query won't store `start_date` or `end_date` values for blog id `9` unless I set them to `varchar` type.

Tried with `timestamp` and `date time` but the query allways will return that 0 rows where affected

the thing is I need to be able to check for rows in a interval of time, and with varchar it makes very complicated.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL recognizes `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` or `'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted here, too: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time parts. For example, `'2012-12-31 11:30:45'`, `'2012^12^31 11+30+45'`, `'2012/12/31 11*30*45'`, and `'2012@12@31 11^30^45'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS'` or `'YYMMDDHHMMSS'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523091528'` and `'070523091528'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23 09:15:28'`, but `'071122129015'` is illegal (it has a nonsensical minute part) and becomes `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` or `YYMMDDHHMMSS` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905132800` and `830905132800` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05 13:28:00'`.

Therefore, the strings `'11/27/2012 00:00'` and `'11/27/2012 00:00'` are not valid MySQL datetime literals.  You have two options (in some vague order of preference, without any further information of your requirements):

1. Provide your literals in a recognised format:

   ```sql
   UPDATE blogs SET
     start_date = '2012-11-27 00:00:00',
     end_date   = '2012-11-27 00:00:00'
   WHERE id = 9
   ```
2. Use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert the string:

   ```sql
   UPDATE blogs SET
     start_date = STR_TO_DATE('11/27/2012 00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i'),
     end_date   = STR_TO_DATE('11/27/2012 00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i')
   WHERE id = 9
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE blogs 
SET start_date = STR_TO_DATE('11/27/2012 00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s') --cast string to date in correct date format
,end_date = STR_TO_DATE('11/27/2012 00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s')--cast string to date in correct date format
WHERE id = 9 --removed quotes as this field's probably numeric
```

If using a timestamp column instead of datetime I think you need to do something like this:

```
UPDATE blogs 
SET start_date = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('11/27/2012 00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s'))
,end_date = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('11/27/2012 00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s'))
WHERE id = 9
```

Comment: More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: No worries - try the second answer above; that should covert the date to a timestamp (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)